# Meaning of equicontinuity in probability theory

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I am reading a paper that says the following:

> Let $(B_t)$ be a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion  and $t_0 >0$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ are fixed. Then the law of the process $(B_t + ct, t \leq t_0)$ is equicontinuous with the law of $(B_t, t \leq t_0)$.

I understand the meaning of equicontinuity in analysis (i.e. when applied to a collection of functions), but I really do not know what it means in the context of probability theory.

Comment: Source? $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did The paper is Conformal Restriction: The Chordal Case, by Gregory Lawler, Oded Schramm and Wendelin Werner. Page 941.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209343v2.pdf page 36. This is odd. Based on the context, what is meant might be that each law is absolutely continuous with respect to the other.